# JavaScript ClassList

Tags: javascript

I recently started the first project tutorial Make a JavaScript Drum Kit in Vanilla JS! #JavaScript30. When im trying to use classList, it doesnt work and I cannot see the problem. I hope some here could help me!

Hugs!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Yazzy and welcome to stack overflow. Help us help you: please post your code here as text instead of images, and make sure to post any error messages you see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here's example of how to use ClassList:

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").classList.add("mystyle");
```

you have to be sure you select the element in right way.
why you don't try to select element by id.